# Restoring database after reinstallation of MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I had to reinstall MySQL some time ago, before doing it I had moved `/var/lib/mysql/mydatabase` to another directory to be able to restore it after installation of MySQL. 
After I installed MySQL I  moved back this directory. When I go to mysql console and use

> SHOW DATABASES;

it returns list of databases and 'mydatabase' is among the list. 
When I switch to using 'mydatabase' and use

> SHOW TABLES;

it shows the list of tables, but when I do any SELECT command I get this error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydatabase.mytable1' doesn't exist

From the very beginning - was it enough to backup only `/var/lib/mysql/< DATABASE_NAME >` to restore database data or have I missed something? If yes then what I could try to fix this issue with 'table doesn't exist'?

MySQL version is 5.7, OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @fancyPants `innodb-file-per-table` was set all the way to 1, but regarding ibdata1 - yes, I haven't saved it, so do you think there's no chance to restore the data?

Comment: Here you go: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 default storage Engine is InnoDB. This stores the data in ibdata,ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1. If you haven't backed up these files then you cannot restore the data.

It is suggestible that instead of moving your database files we should use mysqldump utility.

It is better to use innodb-file-per-table which can store InnoDB tables in a .ibd file per tables.